# Comparing objects

Tags: java, compare

I have a form that let user enter values about address information.
I want to compare the values I get from user, with information stored into ADDRESS table in the database.
I have an entity class

```
public class Address {
  private String gevernate;
  private int homeNo;
  private String neighborhood;
  private String street;
}
```

which is represented as a table in the database called ADDRESS.

and I have a view object for this class which return all address values from db tabel

```
public static Address getAddress(Connection Con, long stdID) {
// select stamatment and result set object.
}
```

The problem I face is that the form may **NOT** contain all values of Address object, it may contains only 2 or three values, it's specified at run time. How can I compare two objects ?

Comment: Which, if any, of the fields above are part of a primary key index associated with the ADDRESS table in your database?

Comment: If one address contains a different number of values than another, how can you compare them?  In other words, how can you be sure that `123 Drury La., Funky Town` is the same as `123 Drury La., Funky Town, CA`?

Comment: STDID number,the address is related to a student.

Comment: @Maxpm, that exactly what I mean, I want to have some ideas to make the comparison.

Comment: To clarify: This doesn't really have anything specific to do with databases or forms, you just want to compare two `Address` objects together, based on a sub-set of the data inside them, and you don't know what that subset will be at compile-time?

Comment: @Alaa Well, you can go through each of the value pairs and `return false` if the pair is unequal and both values are defined.  If it makes it through each test, `return true`.

Comment: @Alaa: I would not use `equals()` to handle this: There are a lot of other ways `equals()` gets used (like the collections framework) which require it to behave in other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an equals method to the class like this:

```
public class Address {
    private String gevernate;
    private int homeNo;
    private String neighborhood;
    private String street;

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Address other = (Address) obj;
    if (gevernate == null) {
        if (other.gevernate != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!gevernate.equals(other.gevernate))
        return false;
    if (homeNo != other.homeNo)
        return false;
    if (neighborhood == null) {
        if (other.neighborhood != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!neighborhood.equals(other.neighborhood))
        return false;
    if (street == null) {
        if (other.street != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!street.equals(other.street))
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: how would you compare two addresses if one have gevernate, homeNo and the other has neighborhood and street defined?

Comment: This works for that too. It checks if null = null first before doing the accual check so you don't have to worry about that

Comment: Going through each attribute is a good idea, I think, I am trying it right now, I wish it works.

Comment: what does getClass() method return?

Answer (score 1):

Define/override equals() and hashcode() for the Address object. Compare as follows:

```
address1.equals(address2)
```

Comment: where define means `override`

Answer (score 1):

I would create an entirely separate class to do the comparisons, because they probably involve special logic and run-time configuration. As your application grows, it might involve some very complex stuff like matching states (`NY` versus `New York`), etc.

Do not use `equals()` for this, which should instead be whatever implementation makes sense for Java collections and general-purpose "is this object exactly the same or not" questions.

Basic idea:

```
int studentId = /* something */;
Connection conn = /* something */;
AddressForm form = /* something */;
Address userEnteredAddress = form.getEnteredAddress();
Address storedAddress = Address.getAddress(connection,studentId);
MyAddressComparer comp = new MyAddressComparer(form);
boolean similarEnough = comp.doMyVagueComparison(storedAddress,userEnteredAddress);
```

It's up to the code in `AddressComparer` to figure out what rules it needs to apply based on what the form was configured to do, and to do all those little special purpose tricks.

Comment: Yes, making separate class from comparison is better than override equals method. But using collection is not clear for me actually.The way of going through each attribute is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just call this pseudocode, because I don't know Java:

```
if (this.gevernate != other.gevernate && this.gevernate != null && other.gevernate != null)
{
    // If both "gevernate" members are valid, but unequal...
    return false;
}

else if (this.homeNo != other.homeNo && this.homeNo != null && other.homeNo != null)
{
    // Repeat for "homeNo" values.
    return false;
}

// Repeat for the other two members.

else return true;
```